# Why in my code goroutine seems to freeze the loop variable automatically

Tags: go, goroutine

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
)


func Print(i int) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}

func PrintR(i *int) {
    fmt.Println(*i)
}


func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go Print(i)   // Get: 1 9 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 0

        //go func() {
        //  Print(i)
        //}()  // Get: 10 10 7 10 4 10 7 10 10 10 10

        //go PrintR(&i)  // Get: 7 10 10 7 10 7 10 10 10 10
    }
    select {

    }
}
```

The 2nd, 3rd example got the expected output, but I have thought that the 1st case's output `go Print(i)` should be similar to the 2nd's since both of them do not use a new variable to freeze the current value of i. What cause the difference?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 0):

Go passes parameter by value. Your first example does actually create a new variable and copy the current index into it before launching the new goroutine, which is the same as your 3rd example.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the value of `i` is evaluated at the time that statement is executed. You see the other behavior in the second example because the anonymous function creates a closure on `i`, so you get whatever value `i` has at the time `Print` is called.

Comment: So in the first case the current value of ```i``` is memorized and stored before the function is executed while in the second case ```i```  always remains the newest? Confused...

Comment: The parameters to a function called with `go` are always evaluated by the caller, so your function always gets the value of `i` at the time of the call. See https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1. In the second example, the anonymous function is a closure because it references the variable `i` which is defined in the scope of the loop. That causes it to share the variable `i` with the other code in the loop. See https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25.